# execute while block until one of three conditions raises

Tags: c#, while-loop

I want to do some actions until one of the following conditions is satisfied^

- `html.IndexOf("/>")==0`
- `html.IndexOf("</"+tagName+">")==0`
- `html[0]=='<'`

where here html is actualy string. 
What Have I tried - just apply OR operation to inversed conditions. But that is wrong. How to do that properly. Here's my code:

```
while((html.IndexOf("/>")!=0)&&(html.IndexOf("</"+tagName+">")!=0)||(html[0]!='<'))
{
    html = html.Remove(0, 1);
}
```

Comment: Consider using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) instead of rolling your own HTML parser.  Somebody else already did all of the hard work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing AND and OR for some reason. You have

```
while(a && b || c)
```

but you want to write

```
while(a && b && c)
```

The code should read:

```
while (   (html.IndexOf("/>")!=0)
        &&(html.IndexOf("</"+tagName+">")!=0)
        &&(html[0]!='<'))
```

I would also echo @cdhowie's comment. Using an HTML parser will make your code easier to read and write, and make it more robust to varied input.

Comment: Thank you. As I understood I have to apply AND operator to inverse condition. Right?

Comment: And one more question - if i will omit brackets in each condition - will it be the same? I mean instead of `while((!a)&&(!b)&&(!c))` to write `while(!a&&!b&&!c)`

Comment: Yes, because equality operators have higher precedence than logical operators

Answer (score 2):

Your code is quite hard to read. You might want to consider splitting the individual conditions to make it easier to maintain:

```
while(true)
{
   if(html.IndexOf("/>")==0) break;             // stop the while loop if we reach the end of a tag
   if(html.IndexOf("</"+tagName+">")==0) break; // or we find the close tag
   if(html[0]=='<')) break;                     // or if we find the start of another tag

   // otherwise, do this:
   html = html.Remove(0, 1);
}
```